# JDO, GAE: Load object group by child's key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo

I have owned one-to-many relationship between two objects:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class AccessInfo {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key keyInternal;     
    ...     
    @Persistent
    private PollInfo currentState;

    public AccessInfo(){}

    public AccessInfo(String key, String voter, PollInfo currentState) {
        this.voter = voter;
        this.currentState = currentState;
        setKey(key); // this key is unique in whole systme
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.keyInternal = KeyFactory.createKey(
                AccessInfo.class.getSimpleName(),
                key);
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return this.keyInternal.getName();
    }
```

and

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class PollInfo
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "currentState")
    private List<AccessInfo> accesses;
    ...
```

I created an instance of class PollInfo and make it persistence. It is ok.
But then I want to load this group by AccessInfo key, and I am getting exception NucleusObjectNotFoundException.
Is it possible to load a group by child's key?

Comment: "Key" (for AccessInfo) is a random alphanumeric string with 12 characters.

PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
  Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
  try {
   tx.begin();
   AccessInfo ai;
   try {
    ai = pm.getObjectById(AccessInfo.class, KeyFactory.createKey(
                        AccessInfo.class.getSimpleName(),
                        key));

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you quote your code for retrieving the AccessInfo object and how you got the "key" that you used ?

Comment: "Key" (for AccessInfo) is a random alphanumeric string with 12 characters. PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager(); Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction(); try { tx.begin(); AccessInfo ai; try { ai = pm.getObjectById(AccessInfo.class, KeyFactory.createKey( AccessInfo.class.getSimpleName(), key));

Comment: Why not just print out what is "pm.getObjectId(ai)" when you persist the AccessInfo object ? and use that in the pm.getObjectById(id) call ? That way you can be sure of having the right key